# Capturing mouse events on horizontal panel in GWT

Tags: gwt

Is there a way to capture mouse events on a horizontal panel in gwt ?
I am trying to capture mousedown or onclick events but m not able to get it working. This is what i have done so far

```
final HorizontalPanel container = new HorizontalPanel() {
        @Override
        public void sinkEvents(int eventBitsToAdd) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.sinkEvents(Event.ONCLICK);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBrowserEvent(final Event event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onBrowserEvent(event);
            if (DOM.eventGetType(event) == Event.ONCLICK) {
                    System.out.println("event type -->> " + event.getType());
            }
            /*if(Event.ONMOUSEDOWN == arg0.getTypeInt())
            System.out.println("event type -->> " + arg0.getType());*/
        }

    };
```

I have no clue why this doesn't work.
any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of manually sinking and reading events, you could consider using [Widget#addDomHandler()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.html#addDomHandler(H%2C%20com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.Type)):

```
HorizontalPanel container = new HorizontalPanel();
ClickHandler cHandler = new ClickHandler(){ /* ... */ };
MouseDownHandler mdHandler = new MouseDownHandler(){ /* ... */ };
container.addDomHandler(cHandler, ClickEvent.getType());
container.addDomHandler(mdHandler, MouseDownEvent.getType());
```

Comment: @Danny Kirchmeier It is interesting. Will it work for FlowPanel, too, for example? Before I tried addHandler(...) instead of addDomHandler() and my flow panel didn't support mouse events so is there a difference between addHandler() and addDomHandler() ? Comment please

Comment: I mean the addHandler() as http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.2/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.html#addHandler%28H,%20com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.Type%29

Comment: @user592704 Yes, this will work for FlowPanels, SimplePanels, Labels, or any other widget. The difference between the two methods is that `addDomHandler` will sink the relevant event bits and add the logical handlers where as `addHandler` only adds the logical handlers. Here is a look at the source(v2.2, line 76): [https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.2.0/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.java#76]

Comment: +1 @Danny Kirchmeier Oh I tried addDomHandler for flowpanel and it worked :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use FocusPanel. For example:

```
HorizontalPanel yourContainer = new HorizontalPanel();

FocusPanel wrapper = new FocusPanel();
wrapper.add(yourContainer );

wrapper.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    // Handle the click
  }
});
```